# How to add image on UITableView cells?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiimageview

How can I add **one image on several cells** of `UITableView`?

I add an image to one top cell, like this:

[image: screenshot]

But after scroll to bottom and top I see this:

[image: screenshot]

Second and third cell has a z-index more that first cell.

How I can do this?

Thanks..

Comment: adjust the cell height according to image height

Comment: @maxname create view and add over the table view by providing x , y values...

Comment: I think your problem solve using Custome Cell.

Comment: Be clear you want to add one image on several images or add image on several cells

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to add the image on the tableView, get the scroll view instance from the tableview using **tableviewobj.scrollview** and then add the image as subview on the scrollview and make the image come front using **bringsubviewtofront** method.

Answer (score 1):

```
UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(3,2, 20, 25)];
imgView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"img.png"];
[cell addSubview:imv];
```

neither you can directly add image to cell

```
 -(UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath 
{    
   static NSString* CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

   UITableViewCell* cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
   if (cell == nil)
      cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

   cell.textLabel.text = @"I'm a UITableViewCell!";
   cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"];

   return cell;
}
```

try this code....

and adjust the image size....

Answer (score 1):

Are you adding the image to the CellView or to the TableView?

You can try the following  function in which you have to specify the filename, position of the picture, size and view to which  you want to add it.

```
- (void)createImage:(NSString *)name
                   inX:(NSInteger)x
                   inY:(NSInteger)y
                 width:(NSInteger)w
                height:(NSInteger)h
                  view:(UIView *)v{

    UIImage *background = [UIImage imageNamed:name];
    CGRect rect = CGRectMake(x, y, w, h);
    UIImageView *yourImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:rect];
    yourImageView.image = background;
    [v addSubview:yourImageView];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Adjust your cell height as a image size.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add image on cell then I would recommend you to make custom cell with imageView .

Answer (score 0):

You can add image as subview to table

```
UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(3,2, 20, 25)];
imgView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"img.png"];
[UITableview addSubview:imv];
```

or

you can increase the height of cell

Answer (score 0):

I did it.

1. Add UIImageView (let's say `img1`) object to UITableView (`table1`)
2. Set `img1.Layer.ZPosition` to 1 that the image was above cells in the `table1`
3. For Headers in sections of table set `img1.Layer.ZPosition` to 2 that a header was above an image

Thanks all for help!

Answer (score 0):

You wouldn't add it to a single cell, but to the tableview itself. Then - in a tableview subclass - you would make sure that in the layoutSubviews the image view stays on top and the position gets adjusted to stay in a fixed place. Or next to a specific cell if you want that.

Answer (score 0):

Use addSubview on tableview directly.

```
let imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height))
imageView.image = UIImage(named: "My Image")
self.tableView.addSubview(imageView)
```